# AWS Device farm: When and how do SetUp and TearDown Suites work in devicefarm's built-in testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I'm using device farm to test android apk files which provides me several information after uploading apk files like videos, screenshots, test logs, suites. And suite is of three types setup, built-in fuzz and tear down suite. But sometimes, one step gets failed and other get passed. So I want to know what `SetUp Suite` and `TearDown Suite` are and how they're working. Attaching [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8QCe.png) of a testing too.

Answer (score 1):

The setup and teardown phase are suites that Device Farm implements in both the custom and standard environments which take care of installing the app, setting the location/locale, and make sure the device is in a valid state. If you look at the logcat or syslog from the device in those setup or teardown suites it will show exactly what the actions were in those suites.

It looks like the device was valid for automated testing in your case but the tests might have been configured for local testing and not for Device Farm. Make sure you don't reference any local paths and that you don't overwrite any capabilities that Device Farm is setting on your behalf.